# Not able to wget from ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, web-crawler, wget

I am crawling a website X over https, I can able to open it in browser and even able to wget from my pc but not able to wget from ec2.

```
Connecting to X|IP|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response.
```

When I created a vpn on ec2 and connected my PC through this vpn, I was able to open website in browser but not able to wget from my pc.

I have tried multiple ec2 instances same thing is happening.

**UPDATE**

Is it possible to detect if the web request is originated from wget or headless browser?

Comment: Some website will reject wget request without a "good" browser user-agent.
Please check out the example here : http://www.dougsparling.org/setting-user-agent-curl-wget/

Comment: @mootmoot I tried multiple user agents still same result, I am able to wget trough my pc but not through aws ec2 servers located at singapore/mumbai

Comment: First, is this the only site that you cannot connect?   Second, have you try phantomjs or selenium headless mode?

Comment: Yes this is the only site, I tried phantomjs same problem occurred. I tried firefox and its working fine with it. I am not able to understand why phantomjs/wget/curl is not working.

Comment: Perhaps the server expect some web header and user agent that phantomjs can't take. This is common technique use by web server to prevent bots like phantomjs. Perhaps you want to diagnose it using sniffer.  Otherwise, you can use selenium + firefox in headless .

Comment: Yeah may be thats the problem, but how phantomjs/wget/curl is working through my pc? I have also tried aws us-east-1 region, Its working fine from there too. Meanwhile, I will try sniffer let see if i can find anything.

Comment: Countless possibilities, e.g.   GeoIP detection, user-agent detection, IP blacklist,  and mix of many. Some admin might want to mitigate DDoS attack. E.g. if your server only server on particular region, you wouldn't want a mass DDoS come from other region.